# Не могу сменить версию node.js через nvm . Error 5 or 145

Tags: node.js, nvm

пытаюсь сменить активную версию ноды, но получаю ошибку 145.

```
nvm install 12.14.0    // всё устанавливается и вижу, если ввожу nvm ls
nvm use 12.14.0   // ошибка доступа 5.  -> захожу с правами администратора - > ошибка 145
```

Что можно сделать, что б не было 145 ошибки ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: запустите в консоли с правами администратора. Windows же?

Comment: @Дмытрык , да, так и делаю и вижу 145 ошибку

Comment: У меня так было...  Ничего не помогло... Переустановка помогла...

Comment: @Air, переустановка чего?

Comment: NVM и  NodeJS...

Comment: @RakzinRoman, 100%? покажите скрин окна командной строки?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>nvm ls

    17.1.0
    15.14.0
    12.16.1
    12.14.0

C:\Windows\system32>nvm use 12.14.0
exit status 145: ����� �� �����.

C:\Windows\system32>   @Дмытрык

Comment: @RakzinRoman, а Вы используете `nvm-setup` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows ? У меня тоже такая ошибка была. И, собственно, исчезла сразу, как запустил от имени администратора. Но я еще, через консоль GitBash, устанавливал настоящий nvm  - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: @Дмытрык получилось. Я посносил и заново поставил и наверное помогло именно то, что я должен запускать именно в папке с проектом, а я запускал с других папок, где нет package.json и подобного. Ну это у меня предположения такие